# Custom service/endpoint address

Tags: .net, wcf

I have created standard WCF Service Application hosted in IIS. In web.config the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Now I can browse the service at `http://localhost:3531/Service1.svc` and endpoint also has the same address. I know that my base address now is `http://localhost:3531/Service1.svc` and I can set relative address for endpoint (for example "MyEndpoint" for `http://localhost:3531/Service1.svc/MyEndpoint`).

But can I change service address to `http://localhost:3531/MyService` and endpoint address to `http://localhost:3531/MyService/MyEndpoint`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **RouteTable.Routes**.
here is an example
http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2013/03/12/exposing-wcf-service-without-svc-extension/